# what is the meaning of # in the view of asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In Asp.net mvc i have a view with .cshtml. i wanna know what is the meaning of writing line between two hash symbol like this code

```
#if(actionName()!=null){ if(actionName()=='Start'){#
```

and what is the different between # and @

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a line between two # has no intrinsic meaning, this line in your example is written as is because it's treated as text and not C#/Razor syntax. This is not because of the usage of #, but it's because you don't enclose your C# code in any valid razor syntax.

You are not using a razor block:

```
    @
    {
      //Everything written inside the razor block is evaluated as C# code. You can 
      have multiple lines  inside this bock
    }
```

You are not using an inline razor statement:

```
@//C# syntax
```

where you can write inline C# syntax that gets evaluated in your code. Normally if you write something like

```
@if(CONDITION)
{

}

@foreach(var x in COLLECTION)
{

}
```

you get to write multiple C# lines in side the enclosing block without the need to define a bigger razor block. See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c)

So to answer your question # in your example has no meaning related to MVC/Razor/C# because it's going to be rendered as Text in  your page as it was written.

```
#if(actionName()!=null){ if(actionName()=='Start'){#
```

it's the same as if you didn't had any other sign other than @. So if you had

```
$if(actionName()!=null){ if(actionName()=='Start'){$
```

it would be written as `$if(actionName()!=null){ if(actionName()=='Start'){$` text in the final page. First one would have be written as `#if(actionName()!=null){ if(actionName()=='Start'){#` text in the final page.

Now if you had `@if(actionName()!=null){ if(actionName()=='Start'){@` this would be evaluated as a razor expression because of `@`, and you would get an error because that is not a valid razor expression.

It doesn't have to do with using a symbol like # or $. You are just writing text any that point (because your are not actually writing a razor expression with `@`), so anything is valid and is going to be rendered as text as is. Symbol or no symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Ahmed, you might find this link helpful:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if

From the above link...

#if, along with the #else, #elif, #endif, #define, and #undef directives, lets you include or exclude code based on the existence of one or more symbols. This can be useful when compiling code for a debug build or when compiling for a specific configuration.

```
// C#
/#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug version");
#endif
```